How to read feather files using polars correctly?
I was checking what is the difference in memory consumed when I read a feather file using pandas vs polars. I see that pandas is consuming 932 MB whereas polars is consuming around 2.5+ gb.
# importing libraries
import os
import psutil
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

# inner psutil function
def process_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    return mem_info.rss/ (1024 ** 2) 

# decorator function
def profile(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        mem_before = process_memory()
        print('BEFORE',mem_before)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        mem_after = process_memory()
        print('AFTER',mem_after)
        return result
    return wrapper

# instantiation of decorator function
@profile

# main code for which
# memory has to be monitored
def func():
    df = pl.read_ipc('data.feather')
    #df = pd.read_feather('data.feather')
func()

Am I reading the feather file correctly using polars ? I was expecting the memory consumption to be less as compared to pandas.

You can use the lazy variant instead: .scan_ipc()
